# Reload cursor after cancel search view on Android

Tags: android, searchview, android-actionmode

I need to reload cursor after query items with search view.

SearchView config

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (newText.length() > 0) {
                mMainFragment.queryNotes(newText);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}
```

Activity declaration

```
        <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

searchable file

[image]

How to handle click on back button? I need to cancel search and reload recycler view in main activity with all items.

When user type backspace in search field I need to reload all items.

The problem with search view default is that I need to do search and show results in the same activity.

Comment: Can't you just reload the activity when a user presses back button? Also, there is the other way of doing searchview that enables same activity

Comment: I think that reload acitvity is a heavy and maybe unecessary process. I have an reference to the fragment in activity and could reload cursor from it. Can you say me what is the other way of doing searchview?

Comment: Not using the searchable xml

Comment: You can write your Adapter to handle insertions and removal of items from a list. Then simply do what you are doing in the above activity to handle searches and when someone cancels search, you can then reload the fragment

Comment: you have `if` in `onQueryTextChange`, add `else` and see when it is executed